# docker compose up showing that server is running but browser showing site can not be reached

Tags: docker, docker-compose

after running **docker-compose up** command

```
Starting tutorial_product-service_1 ...
Starting tutorial_product-service_1 ... done
Attaching to tutorial_product-service_1
product-service_1  |  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
product-service_1  |  * Restarting with stat
product-service_1  |  * Debugger is active!
product-service_1  |  * Debugger PIN: 176-459-861
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
 product-service:
  container_name: tutorial_product-service_1
  build: ./product
  volumes:
   - ./product:/usr/src/app
  networks:
   testing_net:
    ipv4_address: 193.167.10.1
  ports:
   - 5001:80

networks:
 testing_net:
  ipam:
   config:
    - subnet: 193.167.10.0/16
```

This is the URL

```
http://193.167.10.1:5001/
```

but it is showing site can not be reached.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: You generally can't directly connect to a container's private IP address (and correspondingly it's not usually useful to directly configure them).  Connect to your host system's IP address (or `localhost` if the browser is on the same system) and the published port 5001.

Comment: Actually I am using AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance , but it was not running uing my host's IP address , that why I have used that static IP method.
Why it may be not running did I miss something?

this is the public IP of my EC2 instance : http://18.225.37.175:5001/
but no luck

Comment: **docker ps** showing this : 5b5fefaa2766        tutorial_product-service   "python api.py"     About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:5001->80/tcp   tutorial_product-service_1

Comment: Does the host have a firewall?  Does your instance have an AWS security group allowing that inbound connection?